# C API hangs in mysql_query()

Tags: mysql, myisam, mysql-5.7

I have this very strange issue and I cannot reproduce it - it occurs once in ~12 hours **only** for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ReferenceWaves` (
  `ReferenceWave` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'DateTime of the Reference Wave',
  `InstrumentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Triggered` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'When it was triggered'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Assures FAFWE doesn''t use this reference wave when restarted';

ALTER TABLE `ReferenceWaves`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `ReferenceWave` (`ReferenceWave`,`InstrumentId`);
```

Then running this command

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyISAM_ElliottWavesCore.ReferenceWaves 
      WHERE ReferenceWave = '2018-04-02 17:06:00' AND InstrumentId = 73
```

does not return from the `mysql_query()` C function. This occurs more or less once in 12 hours - in the meantime around 10'000 queries like this have been executed without any problem.

Running `SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST WHERE ID=6981;` - where `ID` is the thread id for the query - returns this:

```
ID      USER    HOST                                      DB    COMMAND TIME STATE  INFO
6981    FAEWE   aaeb-app206ly.aaeb-holding.local:52492  (null)  Sleep   1836        (null)
```

After around 5 hours this thread apparently is killed automatically by MySQL and not visible anymore in the `information_schema.PROCESSLIST`.

The table `MyISAM_ElliottWavesCore.ReferenceWaves` has ~4'800 rows and the total size - including the index - is <150KB. I have tables which have million of rows and have size > 1GB but there is never this issue - it is **only in this table** and very unpredictable. You can imagine how frustrating it is.

Any idea what is going wrong?

**Technical data:**

- SLES 12.3 running on XenServer 7.4 as VM
- compiled with `gcc` 7.3 using `-std=c++17` and almost every warning option.
- using `glibc` 2.27 which is separately linked into the project because SLES 12.3 uses 2.22
- MySql Community Server 5.7.21
- C API client 5.7.19

Comment: It was a bug which got fixed. I am now using MySQL 8.x and no problem at all. Thank you for closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a backup every 12 hours?  MyISAM is blocked when dump, `ALTER`, `OPTIMIZE`, and several other operations are done.

Switch to InnoDB to eliminate most of such locks.

You can probably see the offending SQL by getting a full `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`.

Comment: No, I am not doing any of the mentioned commands. [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203304/mysql-query-is-not-passing-the-command-to-the-mysql-server-using-the-c-api) is the more detailed version of the issue. It seems the command hangs but the truth is, the command is **never submitted to the MySQL server**. Just check the link.

Comment: For the moment I cannot reproduce this issue. I changed the engine - as you suggested - to InnoDB - it worked for 300k iterations. Then, I changed it back to MyISAM and it also works.